# How to solve FTP timeouts in C# app

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm using the following C# code to FTP a ~40MB CSV file from a remote service provider. Around 50% of the time, the download hangs and eventually times out. In my app log, I get a line like:

```
> Unable to read data from the transport
> connection: A connection attempt
> failed because the connected party did
> not properly respond after a period of
> time, or established connection failed
> because connected host has failed to
> respond.
```

When I download the file interactively using a graphical client like LeechFTP, the downloads almost never hang, and complete in about 45 seconds. I'm having a hell of a time understanding what's going wrong.

Can anyone suggest how I can instrument this code to get more insight into what's going on, or a better way to download this file? Should I increase the buffer size? By how much? Avoid the buffered writes to disk and try to swallow the whole file in memory? Any advice appreciated!

```
...

private void CreateDownloadFile()
    {
        _OutputFile = new FileStream(_SourceFile, FileMode.Create);
    }
public string FTPDownloadFile()
    {
        this.CreateDownloadFile();

        myReq = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(this.DownloadURI));
        myReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        myReq.UseBinary = true;
        myReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_ID, _Password);

        FtpWebResponse myResp = (FtpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
        Stream ftpStream = myResp.GetResponseStream();

        int bufferSize = 2048;
        int readCount;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (readCount > 0)
        {
            _OutputFile.Write( buffer, 0, readCount );
            readCount = ftpStream.Read( buffer, 0, bufferSize );

            Console.Write( '.' );    // show progress on the console
            bytesRead += readCount;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        logger.logActivity( "    FTP received " + String.Format( "{0:0,0}", bytesRead ) + " bytes" );

        ftpStream.Close();
        _OutputFile.Close();
        myResp.Close();
        return this.GetFTPStatus();
    }

    public string GetFTPStatus()
    {
        return ((FtpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse()).StatusDescription;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use FTPClient as suggested above and got the same timeout error, FTPClient uses FtpWebRequest so I must be missing something but I don't see the point.

After some more research I found that -1 is the value for infinity

For my purpose it is okay to use infinity so I went with that, problem solved.

Here is my code:

//gets file from FTP site.

```
        FtpWebRequest reqFTP;

        string fileName = @"c:\downloadDir\localFileName.txt";
        FileInfo downloadFile = new FileInfo(fileName);
        string uri = "ftp://ftp.myftpsite.com/ftpDir/remoteFileName.txt";


        FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append);

        reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
        reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
        reqFTP.Timeout = -1;
        reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "passWord");
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
        Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        long cl = response.ContentLength;
        int bufferSize = 2048;
        int readCount;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        Console.WriteLine("Connected: Downloading File");
        while (readCount > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
            readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            Console.WriteLine(readCount.ToString());
        }

        ftpStream.Close();
        outputStream.Close();
        response.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading Complete");
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't use FtpWebRequest for FTP access. FtpWebRequest is the most brain-dead FTP API I have every seen.

Currently I use FtpClient http://www.codeplex.com/ftpclient

I also have had good luck with IndySockets http://www.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx

Comment: yes, definitely agree with your assessment of the FTPWebRequest API; only using it cuz I inherited this code and didn't want to make big changes. Just the fact that it has 'Web' in the class name is a clue -- FTP has nada to do with the Web! I'll look at the libraries you reference. Thanks!

Comment: Funny thing is FtpClient from CodePlex uses FTPWebRequest API. And the extension is unnecessary. You should rather look at the Socket class.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dealt with FTP on a code level, but FTP supports resuming.  Maybe you could have  it automatically try to resume the upload when it times out

Comment: yep, good idea -- tho it works around, rather than solves, the underlying problem. The graphical FTP clients rarely time out; why does my code do so?