# What is causing timeout at GetResponse()

Tags: c#, .net, ftpwebrequest, ftpwebresponse

I am trying to access an FTP server via a console application written in c#. My application has a time-out at `FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()` -- the first line inside the try/catch.

I can access the FTP server via Filezilla with the credentials, and the uri + port, supplied to me.

- I have double checked my credentials with my network admin.
- I have tried running my code with and without specifying the port in the URI.
- I have tried adjusting the `FtpWebRequest.Timeout` value.
- I have tried using `FtpWebRequest.ListDirectory`, `FtpWebRequest.ListDirectoryDetails`, and `FtpWebRequest.DownloadFile`.
- I have tried with and without `FtpWebRequest.UsePassive = false`.

  ```
  class Program
  {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          //Uri uri = new Uri(@"ftp://1.2.3.4:990/directory/file.csv");
          Uri uri = new Uri(@"ftp://1.2.3.4:990/directory");

          FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
          ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
          //ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
          //ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
          ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
          //ftpRequest.UsePassive = false;
          ftpRequest.Timeout = Convert.ToInt32(0.5d * 60 * 1000);

          try
          {
              FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
              StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

              List<string> directories = new List<string>();
              string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
              while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
              {
                  directories.Add(line);
                  line = streamReader.ReadLine();
              }
          }
          catch (WebException we)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Message:\r\n\t{0}\r\n", we.Message);
              Console.WriteLine("Response:\r\n\t{0}\r\n", we.Response);
              Console.WriteLine("Response code:\r\n\t{0}\r\n", ((FtpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode);
              Console.WriteLine("Response StatusDescription:\r\n\t{0}\r\n", ((FtpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusDescription);
              Console.WriteLine("Stacktrace:\r\n\t{0}\r\n", we.StackTrace);
          }
          catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("Exception.ToString:\r\n\t{0}", e.ToString()); }
          finally { Console.ReadLine(); }
      }
  }
  ```

Each time I run this code, I receive the following output.

> Message:
>
> > The operation has timed out.
>
> Response:
>
> > System.Net.FtpWebResponse
>
> Response Code:
>
> > Undefined
>
> Response StatusDescription:
>
> Stacktrace:
>
> > at Syste.NetFtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
> >     at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line27

Comment: If you haven't already, you can try setting the `Timeout` value to -1 which represents Infinity. Seems that has solved a similar issue for others as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7665077/5803406).

Comment: @devNull I have tried setting `ftpRequest.Timeout = -1`. I then tried it with `.DownloadFile` and `.ListDirectory`; each try, letting it run for > 7 minutes before killing it.